# Workflow suggestion alternate to "unmergeable commits."

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on a project where a developer clones a repository and then runs a script that tailors some of the files to work with this particular user and their particular project (not the project that was cloned.)

I do want the developer to be able to commit their changes.

I DO NOT want the developer to commit their changes to the master branch of the repo.

The setup I have configured (and scripted) is that a new branch is created based on user and (other) project name, that branch is checked out, the files are modified and (when I finish the script :D ) the files will be committed and pushed back to their (private) branch.

I do not know if our remote repo (Bitbucket) has sufficiently fine grained access controls such that I can allow a developer to clone a project, create a new branch, commit to the branch and yet not be able to merge to 'master' (or any other branch, for that matter.)

(Warning: Git/Bitbucket newb here ...)

It seems to me that forking might be a better alternative to branching but that's not something that (AFAIK) can be done locally and then pushed to the server. And it takes an IT request and a day or two here to create a git repo on Bitbucket. (Well... That's for the company account. Every dev starts with their own account and I suppose a fork could be pushed there. But that would not put the repo where it belongs.)

I did find a question about unmergeable branches and the general solution seemed to be find another model.

This leaves me wondering if there is a better solution to this problem that I am overlooking. Some way to:

clone - yes

commit and push - yes

merge back - NO!

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, while the underlying details differ, "forking" and "branching" in version control (ignoring the underlying VCS) are *logically* the same operation. Forking a repo implies that you have branched *every* branch, creating a clone. Once you translate into a specific VCS like Git, you can enumerate other implementation-specific differences, of course.

Answer (score 1):

On GitLab, you can for instance control the permissions and list the users that can push to master.
http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Bitbucket works similarly, more info at:
https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/

Comment: @HankB does it helps?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info and apologies for not seeing it sooner. I'm still learning how Stackoverflow works. Been lurking for a long time and not posting much. I did not realize I would not get email notification of replies.

Comment: ok no prob. If you find the answer useful, please consider to accept it